# Improper integral involving the Gaussian function

Tags: integration, improper-integrals, contour-integration

Is there an analytic expression for the following integral? Is there a complex plane contour that would accomplish the task?
$$\int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{e^{-x^2}}{x-a}\,dx$$
where $\Im(a)\ne 0$

The contour can not take as its part a half circle going through either the upper or the lower part at infinity of the complex plane, since either path makes the exponential term explode.

Comment: A contour is a path -- a one-dimensional curve. It cannot be an entire half-plane.

Comment: According to Mathematica, the given integral depends on the imaginary error function $\text{Erfi}(a)$.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Faddeeva_function

Comment: @MichaelHardy: You were right that my wording was not precise. I have now edited my question. However, it is hard to make it completely precise with words without actually specifying the contour which I am too lazy to do. I think it is fine so long as people familiar with complex contour integral know what I am talking about.

Comment: @MarcoCantarini: Excellent. Thank you.

Comment: It's easy to find the residue at $a.$ My first guess as to a suitable contour is: $(1)$ first go from $-m$ to $m,$ where $m$ is a positive number, $(2)$ then go from $m$ to $m+2\operatorname{Im}(a),$ $(3)$ then go from there to $-m+2\operatorname{Im}(a),$ $(4)$ then return to the starting point. Then think about $\lim\limits_{m\to\infty}. \qquad$

Comment: @MichaelHardy: Like I have already said in the question, your upper portion of the contour near the imaginary axis will explode as $m\rightarrow\infty$ leading to failure.

Comment: @Hans : Why? The number $a$ is half-way between the real axis and a line parallel to the real axis, and that does not change as $m$ grows. $\qquad$

Comment: @MichaelHardy: Oh, sorry. I misread your previous comment and thought you would push the path parallel to the real axis to infinity. However, I considered this rectangular contour before and did not see how the parallel line could be integrated any easier than the one on the real axis. What is your solution?

Comment: @Hans : I don't know yet. But the integral along that contour is $2\pi i e^{-a^2},$ and it remains equal to that as $m\to\infty.$ So next I would think about whether there is a simple relationship between the integral along the part of the contour that is on the real axis and the part that is parallel to that. And I would think about whether I can prove that the integral along the parts parallel to the imaginary axis approaches $0. \qquad$

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/60251/discussion-between-hans-and-michael-hardy).